Can't get full session info from nextAuth getServerSession()
I am using NextAuth with Discord to get a users information. I need this info on an API route. The standard session provided the username, image and email.This is fine but the issue comes form me needing the customers Discord ID aswell.
To solve this issue I added a callback function to the ...[nextauth].ts file. This works and allows me to get the ID when I use use useSession on the client side. However, when I use getServerSession on the server side I dont get the ID and only get the username,image and email. I have passed AuthOption into the getServerSession call but I have had no luck with this. This is what seemed to help most other people on the Internet.
Here is the code:
root/pages/api/auth/...[nextauth].ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (token) {
        if (token?.picture?.includes("discord")) {
          session.user.id = token.sub;
        }
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);

When I get the session info on the client side I get the following object:
user: {
  email: "xxxx@gmail.com",
  id: "900xxxx08",
  image: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png",
  name: "xx_name_xx"
}

This is done with (root/components/SignInComp.ts):
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"; 
const { data: session } = useSession();

So now the issue!
When I try get this info from the API route I dont get the ID, I get the other info but no ID.
Here is my simplified code (root/pages/auth/api/verifySig.ts):
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import authOptions from "./auth/[...nextauth]";

export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    if (!session) {
      console.error("No session found");
      return res.status(401).send({ message: "Authentication required" });
    }

    const { message, signature, publicKey } = req.body;
    console.log("session", session);
 }
}

This logs:
session {
  user: {
    name: 'xx_name_xx',
    email: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png'
  },
  expires: '2024-06-16T17:12:21.711Z'
}

I have gone through multiple StackOverflow questions and GitHub issues but nothing has helped. The common fix that people have been talking about is adding the authOptions to the getServerSession call but I already do this. My guess it that I could be configuring the authOptions wrong?
I will be super greatful for anyone that can assist.
I tried using getServerSession() but did not get the ID.
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import authOptions from "./auth/[...nextauth]";

export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    if (!session) {
      console.error("No session found");
      return res.status(401).send({ message: "Authentication required" });
    }

    const { message, signature, publicKey } = req.body;
    console.log("session", session);
 }
}


This logs:
session {
  user: {
    name: 'xx_name_xx',
    email: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png'
  },
  expires: '2024-06-16T17:12:21.711Z'
}

